# When I use ansible module expect, I get this msg: The pexpect python module is required

Tags: debian, python, ansible, python3

Some code from yml file:

```
- name: --- run /opt/installer/bin/install.sh ---
  expect:
      command: /opt/installer/bin/install.sh
      responses:
        'Are you installing the application at the central data center? [yes/no default: yes]? [yes]': "\n"
        'What is the code of central data center [default: 01]? [01]': "\n"
        'What is ip or hostname of your server [default: localhost]? [localhost]': 'portal'
```

and I installed `pexpect 3.3` modules on both servers (`ansible` and target `machines`).

```
[root@portal pexpect-3.3]# python setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_py
running install_lib
running install_egg_info
Removing /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pexpect-3.3-py2.7.egg-info
Writing /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pexpect-3.3-py2.7.egg-info
```

when I run playbook I get this error :

```
TASK [ansible-portal : --- run /opt/installer/bin/install.sh ---] *************************************************************************
fatal: [portal]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "The pexpect python module is required"}
```

More information :

```
[root@ansible ansible]# ansible --version
ansible 2.4.2.0
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.5 (default, Aug  4 2017, 00:39:18) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16)]
```

Answer (score 10):

As is typical with some of the modules in `ansible` you have to install certain Python modules on the remote server's side.

- https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/21416

You can use the `pip` module to facilitate this through your `ansible` playbook like so:

```
- name: install pexpect
  pip:
    name: pexpect
  become: yes
```

Your distro may have these available as DEB or RPM files as well. If so you might want to install this Python module using the distro's package manager instead.

In your case it's likely that the Python you installed the `pexpect` module into is not the same one that `ansible` is using. In this case I'd use the system's package manager to install `pexpect`.

#### via package managers

on Debian/Ubuntu systems using apt-get:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-pexpect
```

On Redhat distros (Fedora/CentOS):

```
$ sudo yum install -y pexpect
```

#### References

- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/pip_module.html
- [The pexpect python module is required error even-though it is installed on host machine #21416](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/21416)